# Git: how to set remote in existing repo

Tags: git, gitlab, git-branch

One question please

I have a project on git with differents branches:

Master
Pre
Dev
....

I've installed my project files in another server by FTP (not by git pull or git clone) ir order to create a dev enviroment.

The folder of the project in dev enviroment don't have a git repo. Can I set that this folder is a existing repo (dev branch) without do a git pull or git clone?

Comment: You can try `git init` followed by `git remote add <remote-name> <url>`.

Answer (score 9):

Go to your project folder. Add a remote `origin` with your existing repository URL.

```
$ git init
$ git remote add origin <existing-repo-url>
$ git checkout -b dev             # checkout a new branch 'dev'
```

You need to *stash* (clean working tree and save changes temporary box) your changes before pull the `master`. *Stash* the changes and *Pull* `master` branch changes/commits.

```
$ git add .
$ git stash save 'local changes'

$ git pull origin master         # pull 'master' into 'dev' branch
```

Now, retrieve/pop local changes from stash.

```
$ git stash apply                  # return the code that cleaned before 

$ git commit -m 'message'
$ git push -u origin HEAD          # push to remote 'dev' branch
```

Once all is ok then, clean the stash (*optional*).

```
$ git stash drop
```